# Find view, table with a particular name in multiple databases

Tags: sql-server

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. I want to find the location of the view or a table that has the particular name: `vw_found`, and this in a server that contain many databases.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: I use SQL search for this. (https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/index)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+find+a+sql+server+table+or+view+by+name+in+all+databases&oq=how+to+find+a+sql+server+table+or+view+by+name+in+all+databases&gs_l=psy-ab.3...5810.7945.0.8184.17.11.0.0.0.0.476.1676.0j1j1j1j2.5.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..12.3.1035...33i160k1j33i21k1.0.uqW3Dgw71Xc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BEGIN

DECLARE @CurrentDatabaseId INT = 0
DECLARE @MaxDatabaseId INT = (SELECT
        MAX(database_id)
    FROM sys.databases d)
DECLARE @CheckTableName VARCHAR(100) = '<TableName>'
DECLARE @CheckSchemaName VARCHAR(100) = '<SchemaName>'

WHILE @MaxDatabaseId >= @CurrentDatabaseId
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS (SELECT
                *
            FROM sys.databases d
            WHERE d.database_id = @CurrentDatabaseId)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @CurrentDBName VARCHAR(100);
        DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
        DECLARE @RowCount INT;

        SELECT
            @CurrentDBName = d.name
        FROM sys.databases d
        WHERE d.database_id = @CurrentDatabaseId

        SET @Sql = 'SELECT @RowCnt = COUNT(*) FROM ' + @CurrentDBName + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t WHERE t.TABLE_SCHEMA = ''' + @CheckSchemaName + '''' + ' AND t.TABLE_NAME = ''' + @CheckTableName + ''''

        EXEC sp_executesql @Sql, N'@RowCnt INT OUTPUT', @RowCnt= @RowCount OUTPUT

        IF @RowCount > 0
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Table : ' + @CheckTableName + ' Exists in Database :' + @CurrentDBName
        END
    END

    SET @CurrentDatabaseId = @CurrentDatabaseId + 1

END END
```

Answer (score 0):

**sp_MSforeachdb**

```
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; SELECT DB_NAME(), * FROM sys.objects WHERE Name = ''vw_found'''
```